# Upgrading Windows 2000 domain to window 2003 with Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange

Looking at upgrading our existing Windows 2000 Active directory domain to Windows 2003 Active directory.  Have done it once on a Windows 2000 domain with no exchange server present and all went fine.  Any issues that may come up when upgrading a windows 2000 domain with Exchange 2003 in it?

Comment: Expect issues, there always are issues when doing an upgrade like this.  But, in theory at least, there shouldn't be any.  I would advise making sure you have a good backup of your AD before starting.

Comment: @CodingGorilla This isn't really a major upgrade. Install bunch of new 2003 DCs. Wait. Transfer FSMO roles. Wait. Update DNS settings in DHCP and on anything static. Wait. Demote W2K DCs. Done.

Comment: @MarkM Yea I said the same thing to a customer a couple of weeks ago when upgrading (not in-place, completely new server) Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010.  It tooks us 9 hours that night, and they've been "cleaning it up" for the past two weeks.  I always just like to plan for the unexpected.

Comment: To be fair, a 2007/2010 Exchange **migration** is something **completely** different from an AD upgrade...

Comment: What @Massimo said. Moving mailboxes, etc is a lot different than upgrading AD on separate hardware.

Comment: Not to mention mail flow and web services... even moving Exchange to another server with the exact same release can be a *royal* pain.

Comment: Why *ever* are you upgrading to such old releases?!  Server2008 is mature, and EX2010 should be stable by now... EX2003 is out of support, and Server2003 is only in Extended support.

Comment: Upgrading AD is a (almost) trivial task, upgrading Exchange is *not*. Anyway, the first part of your answer is ok: the new DCs could (and should) very well be 2008 or 2008 R2.

Comment: EX2003 is NOT out of support.

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrade is done properly, there will be no issue at all as long as Exchange is concerned.

Comment: Is there a different forest prep that needs to be run?  I thought I saw something about using the Exchange Server install cd to do the forest and domain prep, I could be mixed up though.

Comment: That has already been done when Exchange was installed. You'll only need to run the prep steps for Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Thanks for the help Massimo, so Exchange 2003 being present in the domain should not matter.  Just a little leary about screwing up the Exchange server.